# Asking a reference about the $p$-Laplacian of $|\nabla u|^p$

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables

It is well-known that for a harmonic function $u$, i.e.
$$ \Delta u=0, $$
the quantity $|\nabla u|^2$ is subharmonic, i.e.
$$\Delta (|\nabla u|^2) \geq 0. $$

Reason:

$$\Delta (|\nabla u|^2)= 2 \nabla (\Delta u) \cdot \nabla u + 2|D^2 u|^2 \geq 0.$$

Now, my question is about the corresponding question for the $p$-harmonic functions, namely:

Suppose that $u$ is a $p$-harmonic function, i.e.
$$ \Delta_p u=0, $$
where the definition of $\Delta_p$ is as follows:
$$ \Delta_p u=\mathrm{div}(|\nabla u|^{p-2} \nabla u)=|\nabla u|^{p-2} \left(\Delta u + (p-2) \left( \frac{\nabla u}{|\nabla u|} \right)^T D^2 u \left( \frac{\nabla u}{|\nabla u|} \right) \right). $$

Notice that for $p=2$,
$$\Delta_2 u = \Delta u. $$

Question: Is the quantity $|\nabla u|^p$, a $p$-subharminc function, i.e.
$$\Delta_p (|\nabla u|^p) \geq 0, $$
as its special case of $p=2$?

A reference is also appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us what you’ve tried so far and where you got stuck? And did you confirm that the inequality holds when the domain is 1-dimensional? That calculation might provide a guide to how the higher dimensional argument should go.

Comment: @DeaneYang: I am going to write the details. Yes, easily it is verified in $1$-dimensional case; even with the equality rather than inequality. Namely, for the $p$-harmonic functions, $|\nabla u|^p$ is also $p$-harmonic.

Comment: By the way, for any harmonic function $u$ we have $\Delta(|\nabla u|)\geqslant 0$. (It is a stronger statement.)